# Assigning a php variable from a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, variables

I am trying to set a php variable for use in a later page with out using $_GET or $_POST.  I am also assigning the same variable to a text box. I already have the function to assign the textbox variable but not the php variable.

```
function setText(data){
  document.getElementById("filtext").value = data.value
  // <?php $_SESSION["provid"] = ?> 
  // I am trying to set the php variable above
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you need something like ajax to send it as either a get or post variable

Comment: PHP = server, JavaScript = client - they can't interact how you want. Use AJAX.

Comment: Cookies would work, but Ajax is your best bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in this case, setting a cookie would be the easiest solution. By setting the cookie using Javascript, the cookie key and value will automatically be sent to PHP with the next page request.

See also:

- http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp, especially "A Function to Set a Cookie"
- http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp, especially "How to Retrieve a Cookie Value?"

Answer (score 0):

To send a value for a server-side language you can use AJAX.

```
function setPHPVariable()
{
    var myAjax;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            myAjax=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        myAjax=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    myAjax.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (myAjax.readyState==4 && myAjax.status==200)
        {
            alert('PHP returned: ' + myAjax.responseText);
        }
    }
    myAjax.open("GET","my_file.php?my_var=12345", true);
    myAjax.send();
}
```

In your PHP code, you can use:

```
$myVar = $_GET['my_var'];
$_SESSION['my_var'] = $myVar; // or even $_SESSION['my_var'] =  $_GET['my_var'];
```

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_examples.asp